# What is Klaus's daughter?

Tags: the-vampire-diaries, the-originals

In *The Originals*, Klaus has got a miracle baby daughter who:

- is a daughter of an original hybrid and a werewolf.
- can heal vampires from lethal werewolf bite (power of original hybrid).
- can create hybrids. A werewolf in transition must drink the blood of the baby (power of human doppelganger blood).

What exactly is Klaus's daughter? A hybrid? A human doppelganger? A werewolf? An original (in the sense, she can't be killed without a White Oak Tree stake)?

Comment: she's a tribrid, which is three

Answer (score 3):

I thought she was a Hybrid like her father. In "[From a Cradle to a Grave](http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/From_a_Cradle_to_a_Grave)", wasn't it sort of explained? Also, didn't Hayley need her blood to turn into a complete hybrid? That was how Hayley became a hybrid after she was killed she still had her babies blood in her, and that means her [baby](http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/Hope_Mikaelson) has to be a hybrid.

This excerpt from the wikia might explain.

> Hope was conceived in the episode "Bring It On", and it was revealed
>   that Hayley was pregnant in "The Originals" and she was born in "From a
>   Cradle to a Grave". She is a Hybrid, and inherited her werewolf gene
>   from both of her parents while her vampire and witch legacy came from
>   her father who is the first Vampire-Werewolf Hybrid and the son of the
>   Original Witch. By her mother she even belongs to the werewolf
>   royalty.

Also fans agree she is a hybrid as seen in this wikia posting.

> As the world's first pureblood Hybrid, the extent and limits of Hope's
>   powers and abilities is unknown.
>
> Hope has the blood of three species in her; vampire, witch, and
>   werewolf. Hope is an active witch because her blood is vampiric, but
>   she is not a vampire. It is unknown if activating her werewolf gene
>   will negate her witch abilities. Hope's blood makes her more resilient
>   than other witches. Hope could possibly practice magic on a higher
>   level than other witches.

In [this source](http://www.bustle.com/articles/24423-the-originals-season-1-finale-cliffhanger-brought-%20esther-mikaelson-back-it-was-creepy-as-hell) it talks about Hayley's baby but calls it the hybrid baby.
But the site was [bustle.com](http://bustle.com), so you decide whether its canon or not.

> Everyone thought Esther would control the witches from The Other Side
>   and force them to search for the **hybrid baby**, who was officially named
>   Hope Mikaelson on Tuesday night. But, apparently, she’s going to head
>   that search herself — and Hayley, Elijah, and Klaus have no idea
>   what’s coming for them.

This answer is basically sort of a comment, because I didn't have room in the comment box for it and it sort of answers the question, so sorry if it doesn't answer.

I think for a more definitive answer, you need to wait for them to tell you. I think the baby is going to have all of her father's powers, plus possibly witch powers, but Niklaus is not a witch so that possibility is not written in stone. I think the baby is definitely a hybrid, but if they decide to make her part-witch that may or may not happen, and you can't tell now. I never read all the books so you might want to read there as well, as that might help you.

As for being an original, if she has all the powers of her father that means that she can't be hurt by white oak.

Comment: For a werewolf to become hybrid, he needs to drink the blood of a doppelganger while in transition, not the blood of a hybrid. Remember, why Klaus needed human Elena in *The Vampire Diaries*...

Comment: But I was under the impression she got her hybrid nature from her father, therefore making her a hybrid. Also her mother drank her blood, if she isn't a hybrid or functioning as a hybrid or doppelganger. Then why did her mother having her blood turn her mother into a hybrid. Or did her mother ingest some doppelganger blood in another episode, which I don't think she did, meaning that the baby is either a untriggered hybrid or something else. But that's not possible since she turned her mother into a hybrid. Or am I mistaken.

Comment: What I am saying: As per rules, her mother needed to drink the blood of a human doppelganger to become hybrid. If drinking baby's blood made her a hybrid, something's wrong.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but they said Hayley was a Hybrid, so what did she get some blood from a doppleganger or what. I think that these kind of answers can't be answered until the show answers them, because Hope can probably turn people to hybrid's without Doppleganger blood, since Hayley was never shown with Doppleganger blood. She probably has different powers that her parents.

Answer (score 2):

Hope is a pure blood hybrid meaning she was born with doppelganger blood unlike Klaus. After Klaus drained it from Elena, he was able to sire hybrids. Hope started siring hybrids from in the womb, meaning she's on a whole different level than Klaus. Normally, you can either be a vampire **or** a witch, never both, because you'd have to die to become a vampire, but Hope was **born** a hybrid, and therefore she is still a witch. Simply put, Klaus is a blend of vampire + werewolf and Hope is a blend of vampire + werewolf + witch.

Answer (score 0):

Hope is part witch, vampire, and werewolf but she is a witch until she triggers her werewolf gene. Her blood can also create hybrids as shown in Season 1 Episode 22, when Haley died with her baby's blood in her and was in transition and had to complete her transition by drinking Hope's blood.

Answer (score 0):

I think that she is a heretic but different from the ones in The Vampire Diaries because she is more powerful.  She is a combination of an original hybrid and a witch from a very powerful bloodline.

Personally I think her werewolf gene may never be triggered because she may end up losing her other abilities and magic - because I have never heard of a werewolf witch.

Comment: Is this meant to be a separate answer to your last one?  Or would it be better to edit your last answer?

Answer (score 0):

Hope is a tribrid, but what has not been adequately answered is what that looks like.

The writers are kept on their toes, because they are making this stuff as it goes along. In the Vampire Diaries, at first you couldn't be a vampire and a witch, but then...there were The Heretics. This doesn't explain exactly how that happened.

Now Hope possesses vampire abilities because of Klaus's supernatural 'loophole', as Hayley died with her baby's blood in her so she changed into a Hybrid also. Questions that come up are

1. if Hayley is a hybrid (and Hope), can their blood cure a vampire from a werewolf bite?
2. I get that Hope can 'grow' up just like a werewolf/human even though she's a vampire, but does she desire blood too since she's got vampire in her?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site!  Usually we like answers that have some kind of evidence to back them up.  For example if you can find a quote from the source backing up your statements.  Also, please don't post separate questions in your answer unless you answer them in the course of answering the original question.

Comment: Heretics were Siphoner not witches .

Answer (score 0):

Hope **is** a witch, werewolf and vampire. She stopped the car before getting to the house that Elijah was in that exploded. She's obviously the strongest one - just no one knows it yet. Plus, you would think that she would technically be the number one **original** because she wasn't created by a witch, she was born that way.

Comment: Welcome to the site! :) I wonder if you have any kind of reference for this? I don't know the work in question, so it may be obvious, but it seems from the body of the question that the asker wasn't sure, so something to back this up would be nice - almost every answer can be proved by quoting an original source, or an interview or something like that. Also, just 'cause you're new, we're a Q&A site here - not so much a forum, so we don't really do chit chat, but clean, clear answers, so you might wanna edit out some of your personal opinions and tagential comments

Comment: There's nothing *wrong* with them in general, they just don't really fit the culture or purpose of this site, which is a little more serious and aimed at evolving a knowledge base out of questions and answers, rather that providing a discussion forum

Answer (score 0):

Hope is NOT a Doppelganger. We had already seen that the nature of hybrids created through Hope was slightly different than those created by Niklaus. 
Klaus' s hybrids are (triggered) werewolves who die with his blood in their systems. During transation they are required to consume the blood of one of Amara's doppelgangers (a Petrova doppelganger) in order to successfully transition. The reason for this isn't explicitly made clear. Whether Esther herself somehow found a way to make these specific conditions the only way that Klaus could make hybrids or whether Nature made it that way and THEN Esther decided to make killing the doppelganger part of the ritual to release Klaus' s werewolf side to ensure he couldn't use her blood afterwards ... we may never know the specifics. In the wake of season 3 of the Originals, it's interesting that Esther put in this failsafe at all. According to the events surrounding how Lucien Castle and the du Martel siblings (Tristan and Aurora) were turned into the first non-Original vampires, it seems that for quite a while the Original siblings were completely unaware that they could turn other people into vampires. This begs the question, what made Esther think Klaus could create more hybrids at all?
Anyway, Hope is a hybrid by birth - unlike Klaus who had to be turned into an Original in order to become a hybrid (otherwise he would have simply remained a werewolf - triggered or not). Because of heredity,  Hope has vampiric power in her blood. It's that simple. One of he parents is part vampire so of course she is part vampire. Since all vampires and vampiric beings have the power to pass on their vampirism to those who die after ingesting their blood, it makes sense that Hope can do the same. Because Hope is a hybrid (due to having predominantly werewolf heritage) she can create more hybrids.
 Hayley cannot create hybrids because she is a non-Original hybrid. This means that Hope is either: Technically an "original" due to not being turned by anyone else; or the ability to create hybrids is just another magical trait she inherited from her father. Now Klaus was given vampirism by dying with enchanted doppelganger blood in his system,  so it makes sense that his hybrids require doppelganger blood to complete their transition because this is their connection to the original spell - without which a werewolf could never have become the first hybrid. Hope's vampirism, on the other hand,  is already in her blood/genes. Thus, hybrids created through her only need her blood to complete the transition - no doppelgangers required. And her blood works because despite her vampiric power she is not undead. She is still a living being.

Comment: Could you split this into a few paragraphs, and maybe add some references?

Answer (score -1):

simple:
Hope is a vamire-werewolf-doppelganger-witch hybrid 
a hybrid because of her father
a with because of her grandmother, and the first borns of every michelson are witches
a doppelganger due to her pure hybrid-witch nature

Answer (score -1):

None of her genes have to be activated.

Whenever a new supernatural creature is born, the rules completely change. The underworld salene daughter is a prime example.
Hope does not have to activate any "gene" they will simple be active from birth 
- She is a hybrid, so she can turn into a werewolf at any time 
- She was born a vampire, so dying to turn does not apply 
- Having witch powers completely changes the rules - her instincts could simple kick in and change the playing field (at the writers discretion) 
BUTTTT mabye just maybe her witch powers are heitict related and she draws her power from her hybrid blood.

But I doubt it because being born all 3 makes her something else inherely capable of making more of anything. Also, she can make more because stated in vampire diaries when Klaus's mom placed the sun moon curse she added if he ever broke it he would need the blood of a doppleganger as a failsafe.
Doppleganger blood is not required naturally.

Answer (score -1):

A witch can be a vampire as well as shown in vampire diaries when Kai was turned he was a heretic as shown when Tyler bit him and Kai healed himself. so which makes hope a heritic though I'm not sure how her werewolf gene would be connected but with all them ability's​ she is so much more dangerous that Klaus

Comment: Eeerrr... What? I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say here. Perhaps [edit] it to make it clearer?